# Set default radio button in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

The below code creates some radio buttons and html to go with them, it works well however I now want to set the first radio button as the default selected one and im not sure what needs to be added.

```
<?php
     for ($i =0; $i < count($packages); $i++){
       echo "<div class='package-outter'>";
       echo "Name: ".$packages[$i]['Package']['name']."<br>";
       echo "Number of Campaigns (per month): ".$packages[$i]['Package']['quantity']."<br>";
       echo "Price: ".$packages[$i]['Package']['price']."<br>";

         if ($i == 0){
           echo $this->Form->input('package', array(
                                   'type' => 'radio',
                                   'options' => array($packages[$i]['Package']['id'] => $packages[$i]['Package']['name'],),
                                   'class' => 'testClass',
                                    ));
         }else{
           echo $this->Form->input('package', array(
                                   'type' => 'radio',
                                   'options' => array($packages[$i]['Package']['id'] => $packages[$i]['Package']['name'],),
                                   'class' => 'testClass',
                                   'hiddenField' => false, // added for non-first elements
                                    ));
          }


          echo "</div>";
          }

?>
```

Comment: Where are you checking to know which one you want to be checked by default?

Comment: sorry i should have said it will be the first button (so where $i=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with CakePHP but a quick Google Search gave me this

```
$options = array(
    'standard' => 'Standard',
    'pro' => 'Pro'
);

$attributes = array(
    'legend' => false,
    'value' => $foo
);

echo $this->Form->radio('type', $options, $attributes);
```

So you should add the attribute 'value' and set it as your default selected radio

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->input('status', array(
    'div' => true,
    'label' => true,
    'type' => 'radio',
    'legend' => false,
    'required' => false,
    'hiddenField'=>false,
    'options' => $status,
    'value' => 1 => default value of input
   ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try the associated value option it should work.

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->input('status', array(
    'div' => true,
    'label' => true,
    'type' => 'radio',
    'legend' => false,
    'required' => false,
    'hiddenField'=>false,
    'options' => array(
            1 => 'High',
            2 => 'Medium', 
            3 => 'Low'
        )
    'value' => 'Medium'
) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->Form->control('company_id', [
 'label' => 'Escolha a empresa', 
 'options' => $companies , 
 'value'=> key($companies), 
 'type' => 'radio', 
 'required' => true
])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO,
To make it easier to understand your answer, please explain briefly what you did here.